# Counting MySQL tables always returns zero?

Tags: mysql, count, database-schema

I'm most certainly missing something really obvious, but I have this really basic MySQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema == "my_table";
```

However, this query always returns zero, even when "my_table" exists. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search table in specific schema (database). You've to provide `TABLE_SCHEMA` in your query.

```
SELECT count(*) from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'my_table' and table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Also execute `SELECT * from information_schema.tables` to see what other information table holds.

Comment: The double = operator was left in by mistake, but adding tale_schema did the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

use single `=` operator in where condition. Try This query

```
SELECT count(*) from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_table';
```

Read it for more information  [Official Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html)

Answer (score 0):

The double `==` is the problem. This is not C/C++ :-)

Answer (score 0):

When I run `SELECT table_schema from information_schema.tables`, it returns database names, not table name.